# Monolog and Symfony logs

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

Please, how to configure a custom path for Symfony logs using monolog?

My application logs is working fine, but I cant find the log for some errors, like this:

`InvalidConfigurationException` in `VariableNode.php` (I can't see this log on screen but I can't find on log files)

Actually, I'm using this config:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/app.log"
            level:  error
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config is only dealing with messages that are of log level `ERROR` or higher (this also includes `CRITICAL`, `ALERT`, and `EMERGENCY`). If you want to have logged everything into the `app.log` file, change the value of the minimum log level to be logged to that file to `debug`.

Alternatively, you can configure different handlers to have more verbose messages go to, for example, a `debug.log` file:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/app.log"
            level:  error
        rest:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/debug.log"
            level:  debug
```

Comment: thanks for reply, It's strange but I put this config but the error still not appear in the app.log or debug.log =(

Comment: The example was not completely right (the `handlers` option was duplicated and the handler names were the same). Can you try it again with the updated configuration example?

Comment: sure, I'm getting this error:`InvalidConfigurationException in BaseNode.php line 313:
Invalid configuration for path "monolog.handlers": The "debug" name cannot be used as it is reserved for the handler of the profiler` (this message also is not on logs, only on symfony dev screen)

Comment: Oh well, instead of `debug` just use something like `rest` (I updated above, but you should probably find a better name).

Comment: tks! the debug log is working fine, but I'm still can catch that InvalidConfigurationException in the logs (this is the error when I have some parameter configured wrong)

Comment: Ah, this will not make it to the logs as the error happens when building the container. In that state Monolog isn't configured as it depends on configuration that is parsed when building the container. So I do not think you can do anything about that specific message. Sorry I misunderstood your issue.

Comment: tks! do you know if I can find this message on some default log file?

Comment: Probably the log PHP log file (if configured, the web server's error log otherwise).

Comment: I found the messages on php logs, you are right tks!